# Dynamically creating concentric div given the inner div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have  2 divs as :

```
<div id="outer">
     <div id="inner">
     </div>
</div>
```

The inner div has some fixed height(H) and width(W) . Initially the "outer" div doesn't
have width and height.Also has same top and left values.(same origin)

How can I create/place a concentric "outer" div (or make the "outer" div concentric)
with some height OH and width OW ?

The problem is I know W and H (width and height of inner div).

I need the outer div with dimensions OH and OW (width and height of outer div).

**Added Edit**:
Is there way to calculate left and top for the outer div instead of doing it the CSS way?

**Edit2** : The earlier image was bit misleading. the divs  are more rectangular than square.So the padding left and right are equal  as well as top and bottom but different values.

**ie. In some cases , dW is  not equal to  dH**

[image: concentric divs]

Added [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CYjAR/6/)

Also looking for jquery / js solution.

Comment: just create a fiddle with what you have done yet

Comment: Am I missing something, or is this just a matter of adding some padding on the outer div?

Comment: srry edited my queston and added fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Float the outer div - this will force the width to the width of the contents

2) Add some padding on the outer div

```
#outer
{
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
}

#inner
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

[Here's a working example](http://jsbin.com/atavub/1/edit)

Comment: nice thx.. also is there way to calculate left and top for the outer div instead of doing it the CSS way?

Comment: sry i have added another edit. basically the padding is not equal in some cases,updated image too

Comment: So, use unequal padding. Something like `padding: 200px 50px 30px 65px;` This padding could also be calculated and set via JavaScript if necessary.

Comment: I m not really clear on why you wouldnt want to do this with CSS. Javascript should be a last resort for styling that can first be accomplished with css. If you know the inner boxes dinmensions then best practice would be to use the method that I showed you but change the margin top vs right etc.

Comment: I'm more of a fan of padding for one reason: margin collapse. Two adjacent margins will collapse into one, with the larger one taking precedence. So, margins *could* result in some unintended effects.

Answer (score 1):

From http://jsfiddle.net/judsonmusic/jvyMF/1/

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box
}  
#outer{

    border:1px solid grey;
    display: inline-block;

}
#inner{

    border:1px solid grey;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float: left;
    margin:50px;

}
```

Comment: thx..also like you said in your comments below.. how can i do it jquery way? i added an edit to question for same

Comment: Are these divs absolute positioned?

Comment: Essentially, $('#inner').css({ margin: $('#inner').outerWidth(true)/2});

Comment: sry i have added another edit. basically the padding is not equal in some cases,updated image too

Comment: You would basically set margin left and right seperately the margin top and bottom separately using the same jquery methodology.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set the margin on the inner div 1/2 of its width or height. This would make the div around it concentric to it.

Comment: I was thinking it would be `((outerHeight - innerHeight) / 2)` and `((outerWidth - innerWidth) / 2)`.

Comment: Making the margin half of the width just isn't going to work. Try it.